# VBA,Combine .Formula with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vba code which puts a formula in a cell.

```
 .Range("D" & lastrow + 1).Formula = "=INDEX(Spread!$C:$C, MATCH(1,INDEX((A330 = Spread!$A:$A) * (""Stack"" =Spread!$B:$B),),0))"
```

How can I change `A330` in my formula to vba code like  `Worksheets("Manager").Range("C2").Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concate it like a normal string using the `&` operator. Since you are not joining text ,but rather a VBA object, do not wrap quotes around the object.

```
"=INDEX(Spread!$C:$C, MATCH(1,INDEX((" & Worksheets("Manager").Range("C2").Value & "= Spread!$A:$A) * (""Stack"" =Spread!$B:$B),),0))"
```

Comment: thanks. I think you  put an extra `"` at the end of `.value` . I am having trouble with this though, the `Worksheets("Manager").Range("C2").Value` is providing the right value in the formula, which is same as `A330`.. but its a date not sure if this is matching correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also store the data in a variable and use it instead of A330. This way you can always use newly created variable inside your code anytime anywhere in your code

```
myData = Worksheets("Manager").Range("C2").Value
.Range("D" & lastrow + 1).Formula = "=INDEX(Spread!$C:$C, MATCH(1,INDEX((myData = Spread!$A:$A) * (""Stack"" =Spread!$B:$B),),0))"
```